# Find first blank cell of a column in a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to find the first blank cell of a column in a table with this code:

```
'Find next blank cell in results sheet
lLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'Paste results in the result sheet
.Range("A" & lLastRow).Value = Worksheets(strSheet).Range(strAddress).Value
```

The problem is that it only finds the first blank cell after the table. Any idea how to make it work inside the table?

Answer (score 1):

The `.End` function also has options other than `xlUp` so you can start at the top and work down.

`lLastRow = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1`

Comment: Good answer! Shorter than mine.

Comment: It still jumps to the first empty cell after my table.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Public Function IdentifyLastRowInBlock() As Long
  With Sheet1
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim blankRow As Long
    blankRow = .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 1)).End(xlDown).Row + 1
  End With
  IdentifyLastRowInBlock = blankRow
End Function
```

Note that this will return the last unused row starting at row 3. Not knowing your code, I simply hard coded the start point - you'll have to modify that to fit your circumstances. I'd actually recommend making it a parameter to the function so it's more flexible in the future. It's also hard-coded to look in column 1 ("A"), that could also be made a parameter.

Also, note that if the table happens to be "full" in column 1, it will find the first row *after* the table. The nifty thing about tables is that they auto expand, so if you put a value in that first row after the existing table, Excel will expand the table for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with this witch works

On Error Resume Next
    lLastRow = Range("A29:A67").Find(What:="", _
                    After:=Range("A29"), _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0

```
            'Paste results in the result sheet
                .Range("A" & lLastRow).Value = Worksheets(strSheet).Range(strAddress).Value
```